# How to create a table from a JSONB column in PostgreSQL, with nested objects as separate tables?

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL table with a JSONB column that contains JSON data representing different entities. I would like to create a new table from this JSON column where each field becomes a column in the new table. Additionally, for nested JSON objects, I want to create separate tables to represent the relationships.

For example, let's consider the following JSON data:

```
{
  "id": "0001",
  "type": "donut",
  "name": "Cake",
  "ppu": 0.55,
  "batters": {
    "batter": [
      { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
      { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" },
      { "id": "1003", "type": "Blueberry" },
      { "id": "1004", "type": "Devil's Food" }
    ]
  },
  "topping": [
    { "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
    { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
    { "id": "5005", "type": "Sugar" },
    { "id": "5007", "type": "Powdered Sugar" },
    { "id": "5006", "type": "Chocolate with Sprinkles" },
    { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
    { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
  ]
}
```

I want to create a new table where the fields **id**, **type**, **name**, and **ppu** will be columns. Additionally, the **batters** field should be represented as a separate table with columns **id** and **type**, and the **topping** field should be represented as another table with columns **id** and **type**.

How can I achieve this in PostgreSQL? Is there a way to automatically generate the necessary tables based on the structure of the JSON data?

This is exactly what I need to do - https://www.codeflu.com/postgreson/new. This webapp is doing the same thing.

Here I am able to create view manually

```
CREATE OR replace VIEW public.my_table AS
SELECT
       field.id,
       field.type,
       attr.name,
       attr.ppu,
       attr.batters,
       attr.topping
FROM   existing_table,
       jsonb_to_recordset(existing_table.jsonb_column) AS attr(id INTEGER, type VARCHAR, name VARCHAR, ppu decimal, batters JSONB, topping JSONB);
```

But how can I do it for dynamic json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A table can be filled using the following query:

```
insert into mytable(id, type, name, ppu)
select jsonb_column->>'id' as id,
       jsonb_column->>'type' as type,
       jsonb_column->>'name' as name,
       (jsonb_column->>'ppu')::decimal(5,2) as ppu
from existing_table
```

To create **topping** and **batters** you will need to use `jsonb_array_elements` to extract rows from array of objects :

```
insert into batters
select (b.value->>'id')::int as id, b.value->>'type' as type
from existing_table
cross join jsonb_array_elements(jsonb_column->'batters'->'batter') as b
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/DT8KnPKl)